# Is there a word with phobia suffix for fear of waking others up?

Tags: single-word-requests

I usually come home after basketball at like 12:30 a.m. and at this time my mom and sister usually sleep (my Dad though is usually up). When I come home, I don't go to sleep right away and will sometimes eat or do something else. When I do so, I do it in stealth, so that I don't wake up anyone. I do out of two things, to be polite as I do not want to wake anybody up and also the fact that if I make a loud noise and wake my mom up, my mom will get mad and lecture me. Does this count as a phobia? In addition, if it does what would the name of it be.

Comment: Even though only an earthquake would wake my wife and children, I'm always extra careful not only at home but anywhere where I might wake someone up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be considered a phobia if just the thought of awakening someone from sleep aroused autonomic symptoms in you.  You'd feel nervous, breathe fast, have strong heartbeats, or any other undesirable symptom.  Otherwise, I would say that you are pretty much concerned for the well-being of your folks.  A sensible and conscientious person.

But, to answer your question, assuming it is a phobia, I can only come up with "atelophobia" which means "fear of imperfection" which is not specific for what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

What you describe would not be considered a phobia, which is an irrational fear of something. On the contrary, you are being quite rational, and quite considerate. If you yourself had an irrational fear of waking up, then that would be "egeirophobia".