# Is there a phobia for waking others up?

Tags: phobias

Let's say, that I'm at a sleepover and got put in the corner with no direct way of getting to the door without disturbing other people. If I wake up, having to use the restroom or get a drink, I get extremely anxious and have to find some complicated way of getting around the other people without waking up, which can get so bad that I start sobbing. I have always had this problem ever since I was a kid and I would get really scared to wake my mom up if I threw up or she slept in too long. Is there a phobia-suffix word for this or a way to get over it?

Duplicate of [Is there a word with phobia suffix for fear of waking others up?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/272392/is-there-a-word-with-phobia-suffix-for-fear-of-waking-others-up?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Welcome to EL&U! For a 'way to get around it', I would suggest finding a good therapist you can trust.